# Category of 3-term sequences

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Is there a name for the following categorical concept? If so, where can I read about it?

Given some category $\mathcal{C}$ we build a new category $\mathcal{C}^3$ whose objects are $3$-term sequences of objects with morphisms from $\mathcal{C}$ 
$X\to Y \to Z$  and where a morphism consists of morphisms $X\to X'$, $Y\to Y'$ and $Z\to Z'$ such that the following diagrams commute

[image] [image]

Comment: For the objects, do you mean $Y\leftarrow X\rightarrow Z$? That would better match your definition of morphisms. If that is the case, you are looking for [spans](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/span). Otherwise, I don't think the category has a name, but it looks like the category of functors from $\mathcal I$ to $\mathcal C$, where $\mathcal I$ is the category with three objects and morphisms $\cdot\rightarrow\cdot\rightarrow\cdot$, i.e. $\mathcal I$ is a total order with three elements (this is not a standard notation).

Comment: I'm trying to capture transformation of asymptotics. For example one may try to understand limits of convergent sequences $C(\mathbb{N})$ by considering some transformation of $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\to C(\mathbb{N})  \to \mathbb{R}$ where we can only guarantee that the limits transform nicely for $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Ok, so neither of my previous constructions were correct. I'm not sure I can be of much help, but I'll ask one more question: if I understand correctly, the map $\ell^2(\Bbb N)\rightarrow\Bbb R$ sends any $\ell^2$ sequence to $0$, right?

Comment: Yes but I think considering translates $\mathbb{R} + \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ should also be legitimate. The case where $X\to Z$ is a zero morphism is certainly a important case though. (And more generally colimits of constant morphisms may be interesting.)

Comment: @NoelLundström Not quite right? There is no requirement that the the naturality square corresponding to $2 \to 3$ (or $Y \to Z$ in OP's question) commutes.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Oh yes that's right. Maybe there's something with comma categories here? Let $\mathcal D = a \leftarrow b \rightarrow c$ then there is a functor $T:D \rightarrow 3$ which takes $a \mapsto 2, b \mapsto 1, c \mapsto 3$. Using this functor seems like a promising approach but I can't figure out the specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit too long for a comment, but I'm not sure it really answers the question.
It's an alternate construction that realizes your category as a full subcategory of the category of spans in $\mathcal{C}$.

The morphisms here look like morphisms in a category of spans.

In other words, this looks like the functor category $\newcommand\C{\mathcal{C}}\newcommand\span{{\cdot \leftarrow \cdot \to \cdot}}\C^\span$.

However, we really want the full subcategory, $\newcommand\D{\mathcal{D}}\D$, of spans 
$$Y\overset{f}{\leftarrow} X \xrightarrow{h} Z$$
such that $h$ factors through $f$, i.e., 
such that there is some map $g:Y\to Z$ with $h=gf$.

Now $\D$ is not isomorphic to the category in your question, since your category remembers the factorization of $h$. However, these two categories are equivalent.

We define a functor that sends the object $X\xrightarrow{f} Y\xrightarrow{g} Z$ 
to the span $$Y\overset{f}{\leftarrow} X\xrightarrow{gf}Z.$$
The morphisms in the two categories are the same, so this functor is fully faithful, and $\D$ is essentially by definition the image of this functor, so this functor is also surjective. Therefore this functor is an equivalence.

**Comment**

I'm not sure there is a great definition of your category (up to isomorphism) other than the one you've given, because your choice of morphisms causes the category to "forget" about $g:Y\to Z$ and only remember the composite morphism $h:X\to Z$. As long as $gf=g'f$, the two objects 
$$X\xrightarrow{f} Y\xrightarrow{g} Z$$
and 
$$X\xrightarrow{f} Y\xrightarrow{g'} Z$$
are isomorphic via the morphism $(1_X,1_Y,1_Z)$.

Comment: Is there a lot known about spans? Where could I learn more?